# From which book these articles have been taken?

Tags: reference-request

Can anyone tell me from which book these articles have been taken? It says "University Mathematics Handbook". However, on searching the internet I am not able to find this particular book. Please provide me the link to this book.

[Book](http://schoolbag.info/mathematics/university/index.html)

Comment: In my opinion, it might be for the best: the notation used in the link is outstandingly bad (even more so for a work dating to 2015, way into LaTeX era).

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Underwood Dudley [agrees](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/university-mathematics-handbook).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos If the printed version matches the one online, Underwood is way too kind. In the table of notations there's a grid that flat-out *lies* about the Greek alphabet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not try *very* hard, did you? It's [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B014BQ3QOA).